# Cannot redeclare class ControllerEventTheme in /home/uneguihu/public_html/catalog/controller/event/theme.php on line 47

Tags: php, opencart

I'm having some hard because some of the images are not displaying and I found this error from the Error Log:

> Cannot redeclare class ControllerEventTheme in /home/uneguihu/public_html/catalog/controller/event/theme.php on line 47

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class ControllerEventTheme extends Controller {
public function index(&$view, &$data, &$output) {
    if (!$this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') .         '_status')) {
        exit('Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!');
    }

    // This is only here for compatibility with older extensions
    if (substr($view, -3) == 'tpl') {
        $view = substr($view, 0, -3);
    }

    if ($this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default') {
        $theme = $this->config->get('theme_default_directory');
    } else {
        $theme = $this->config->get('config_theme');
    }

    if (is_file(DIR_TEMPLATE . $theme . '/template/' . $view . '.tpl')) {
        $view = $theme . '/template/' . $view;
    } else {
        $view = 'default/template/' . $view;
    }
    /*          
    // If there is a theme override we should get it                
    $this->load->model('design/theme');

    $theme_info = $this->model_design_theme->getTheme($view, $theme);

    if ($theme_info) {
        extract($data);

        ob_start();

        eval('?>' . html_entity_decode($theme_info['code']));

        $output = ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        if (is_file(DIR_TEMPLATE . $theme . '/template/' . $view . '.tpl'))    {
            $view = $theme . '/template/' . $view;
        } else {
            $view = 'default/template/' . $view;
        }       
    }
    */
}
}
```

Comment: It means, some other file before already included this file, so the class is declared before. Check what is in _/home/uneguihu/public_html/catalog/controller/event/theme.php_ If it is a `require` or `include` rewrite it to `require_once`

Comment: @karacsi_maci Thanks for your help.